# Red shift in Schwarzschild geometry

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, doppler-effect, redshift

I found the following derivation of the famous red shift formula in a textbook:

Let a photon be emitted radially from $r_{e}$.  A stationary observer receives the photon at a radius $r_{o}$.

In locally Minkowskian coordinated, the receiver has a 4-velocity $\hat{u}^{\mu}=(c,0,0,0)$ and receives the photon with a four momentum $\hat{p}^{\alpha}=(\hat{E}/c,\hat{\vec{v}}).$ Note that $\hat{E}=\hat{p}^{\alpha}\cdot \hat{u}_{\alpha}$ is a Lorentz scalar and therefore valid in any coordinate system.

Hence we can use the formalua $E=u^{\mu}p_{\mu}$ for the energy of the photon, where $u$ is the 4-velocity of the observer/emitter and p is the 4-momentum of the photon in the system of the observer/emitter.

It follows: $$\frac{\omega_{o}}{\omega_{e}}=\frac{E_{o}}{E_{e}}=\frac{\sqrt{1-2\mu/r_{e}}}{\sqrt{1-2\mu/r_{o}}}\frac{p^{0}_{o}}{p^{0}_{e}},$$ where we have used that $u_{e/o}=(c\mathrm{d}t/\mathrm{d}\tau,\vec{0})=(c/\sqrt{1-2\mu/r_{e/o}},\vec{0}).$

Now the author claims that $\frac{p^{0}_{o}}{p^{0}_{e}}$ is equal to 1, "because of the geodesic equation".....Can someone explain this to me? I dont get it....Why shoud it be 1? Isn't the energy contained in the zero component of the 4-momentum? Isn`t this claim than equal to say that $\omega_{o}/\omega_{e}=1$?

Answer (score 2):

I think a more general approach might help here.

The point here is that if $K^\mu(x)$ is a Killing vector field and $\gamma^\mu(\lambda)$ is a geodesic, then $$Q(\lambda)=K_\mu(\gamma(\lambda))\dot{\gamma}^\mu(\lambda)$$ is conserved along the geodesic. This follows from combining the Killing equation $$\nabla_\mu K_\nu+\nabla_\nu K_\mu=0\tag{1}$$

with the geodesic equation $$\dot{\gamma}^\mu \nabla_\mu \dot{\gamma}^\nu=0.\tag{2}$$

To show this just differentiate $Q(\lambda)$ along $\gamma$:

$$\dfrac{dQ}{d\lambda}=\dot{\gamma}^\mu \nabla_\mu [K_\nu \dot{\gamma}^\nu]=\dot{\gamma}^\mu \dot{\gamma}^\nu \nabla_\mu K_\nu+K_\nu \dot{\gamma}^\mu \nabla_\mu \dot{\gamma}^\nu\tag{3}$$

Now the first term vanishes because of (1) which implies that $\nabla_\mu K_\nu$ is skew-symmetric while $\dot{\gamma}^\mu\dot{\gamma}^\nu$ is symmetric. The second term vanishes because of (2).

In your case the point is that you have a set of observers whose four-velocities are parallel to a timelike Killing vector field $K^\mu$. This means there is a function $\alpha(x)$ such that $Z^\mu (x) = \alpha(x) K^\mu(x)$.

Now suppose $\gamma(\lambda)$ is the worldline of a photon and that it connects two events: $x_e=\gamma(0)$ (emission) and $x_o=\gamma(1)$ (observation). Then one of such observers is at the emission event, with four velocity $Z^\mu(x_e)$ and will observe the photon emitted with energy $\omega_e = -Z_\mu(x_e)\dot{\gamma}^\mu(0)$.

Another observer is at the observation event, with four-velocity $Z^\mu(x_o)$, and will observe the photon with energy $\omega_o = -Z_\mu(x_o)\dot{\gamma}^\mu(1)$.

Now what connects the $\omega_o$ and $\omega_e$ is the fact that $K_\mu \dot{\gamma}^\mu$ is constant along the geodesic as I invite you to check and in the end reproduce the formula you give in the more general context.

Finally you can see what $\alpha$ must be recalling that observers have normalized four-velocities $Z_\mu Z^\mu = -1$ whereas Killing vectors don't necessarily have. This demands $\alpha^2 K_\mu K^\mu = -1$ from which we obtain $\alpha = \sqrt{-1/K_\mu K^\mu}$ which is real because $K^\mu$ is assumed timelike.

For Schwarzschild $K = \partial_t$ and $K_\mu K^\mu = g_{00}$ and you get your formula.

Answer (score 1):

One way to see this is from the Lagrangian: It is time-independent in Schwarzschild coordinates, so the corresponding canonically-conjugate momentum is conserved.

Alternatively, you can compute the Christoffel symbols directly and write down the geodesic equation. This should tell you that the time-component of photon velocity will be constant. As solving the geodesic equation yields affinely parametrized curves, so will the time-component of momentum (given an affine parametrization, momentum and velocity are related by a constant factor).